# Making object chain of element by adding parent name

Tags: javascript

I want to make chain that contain parent element and return me any attributes of top parent (class or id) by using there respective symbol (. and #). I have tried it but ran to infinity loop

html structure:-

```
<div id="main">
   <p>Hello Alisha..</p>
   <div class="container">
     <div id="toplayer">

     </div>
     <div class="mid_layer">
         <ul>
            <li>javascript</li>
            <li id="target">qbasic</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My js code:-

```
var t = document.getElementById("target");

 function  chain(el) {
    var f = {};
    var m = el;
    if (el !== null && el !== undefined) {
      var y = m.parentElement;
      while(null !== y){
        var r = {};
        r['parent'] = y;
        f[m.tagName] = r;
        var m = y;
      }
      return f;
     }
   }
  chain(t);
```

Loop dosn't stop in above program.

### Please don't suggest me idea using jquery

Comment: You aren't updating `y` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the assignment of `y` inside the loop (as DrC commented), as it is now `y` is always `not null`, hence the infinity loop.

```
var t = document.getElementById("target");

 function  chain(el) {
    var f = {};
    var m = el;
    if (el !== null && el !== undefined) {
      var y = m.parentElement;
      while(null !== y){
      y = m.parentElement;
        var r = {};
        r['parent'] = y;
        f[m.tagName] = r;
        var m = y;
      }
      return f;
     }
   }
  chain(t);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get the top parent element attribute, you dont need to create any chains. There are built in properties that collects that data anyway:

```
var t = document.getElementById("target");

console.log(t.offsetParent.children[0].id)
```

You can easily check available methods or properties in your Chromes console:

```
var t = document.getElementById("target");
dir(t)
```

Comment: what is dir() is this built in function??